# How can I implement my binary countdown from the output of JK flipflops to two seven segment displays from 15-0?

Tags: logic-gates, timer, flipflop, counter, 7segmentdisplay

[image]

I am currently making a 2-way traffic stoplight.  The stoplight signals are now fully functional. I have no idea how I can implement the 4 bits (not including my MSB because I just need to display 15-0) from my binary countdown onto the 7 segment.

Note: the 7 segment display in my current circuit is just a way so that my countdown timer display will turn off whenever the output of the MSB of my countdown is 1.

Comment: Yuan, if I am skimming this correctly, then you believe you have the right states and the right number of states for your traffic stoplight system and that you now want to add a countdown for a crosswalk when the light is red. Do you have enough states, while red, to countdown all the way from 15 to 1 (and perhaps 0) for one of the directions? (You may. I'm just asking.) And it may be the case that when Q1 is active (oddly arranged) that this is when you want the countdown to start, using the clock input. Is that about it?

Comment: (More info about your design, states, state transitions, and where the 15-0 fits in all of it would be nice to have, as well. Reverse engineering isn't something you should ask of us.)

Answer (score 1):

Your 7seg driver is a BCD to hex. You would have to use a binary to decimal 7 seg driver, or perhaphs much more easy these days, a simple microcontroller.

You could just plug your counter bits into the driver but keep in mind that the output is hexadecimal and might not be what you want.